# xcode button is not working inside a storyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7

I added a button to my storyboard:

[image]

and I created a Sent Event and Referencing Outlet:

[image]

Here is the code in my .h file:

```
@interface LHCompletionVC : UIViewController<SGridDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate,UIPickerViewDelegate,
UIPickerViewDataSource,UIAlertViewDelegate>
{

    IBOutlet UIButton *areaButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *unitButton;
    IBOutlet UIView *searchView;
    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *userLabel;
    IBOutlet UIButton *testBtn;
}
```

and here is the code in my .m file:

```
- (void)CustomAlert:(NSString*)reason
{
    UIAlertView *customAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:reason delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [customAlert show];

}

- (IBAction)testBtnPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self CustomAlert:@"Testing"];
    return;
}
```

But when I run my code, i get no errors, and I set a break point on testBtnPressed and when I click on my buttonm, nothing happens, no break point, no error, no alert either. Weird...does anyone have any ideas why this does not work?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Please change the position of the Button. In most of the cases when button is not clickable, there might be a transparent View on the button, or the frame of the button is not inside clickable View.

Here are few methods to debug

- Change the postion of the Button to check if something is not
  overlapping.
- Change the color of Background Views to distinguesh
  between views and their frames.
- View your UIView Hierarchy via [Spark
  Inspector](http://sparkinspector.com) OR
- You can inspect view hierarchy with Xcode. Debug -> View Debugging -> Capture View Hierarchy. (App needs to be running and it's a feature in Xcode's Debug menu.

Comment: You can inspect view hierarchy with Xcode. Debug -> View Debugging -> Capture View Hierarchy. (App needs to be running and it's a feature in Xcode's Debug menu, not Simulator's).

Answer (score 2):

Check your View "User Interaction Enabled"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Fix any auto-layout warnings** related to the button and/or nearby UI elements.

In my case everything previously mentioned looked good in the attribute settings, Interface Builder including the view hierarchy and in the simulator. But fixing an auto-layout warning cleared up the problem.